# Catching mysql_query error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to stop the mysql_query error from being output onto my form. Currently if there is no location found, I receive the error

"Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 11"

I am trying to catch this error, and instead assign the $location variable to not found. My code for attempting this is below, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
$query3 = "SELECT `location` FROM location WHERE vin = '$vin' LIMIT 1";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);

if (!mysql_result($result3,0)) {
    $location = "Not found";
} else $location = mysql_result($result3,0,0);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mysql_result()` generally shouldn't be used. You'd be better off with something like:

```
$result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_numrows($result3) == 0) then
   $location = "not found";
} else {
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
   $location = $row[0];
}
```

Your error is caused by the fact that the query returned no rows - e.g. nothing matched. You then tried to retrieve the first field in the first row of that result set, a row which doesn't exist. Checking the number of returned rows with `mysql_numrows()` is safer, as that works whether the query found nothing or a bajillion rows.

Comment: This should be the proper way to solve this. Don't hide your problems, solve them instead ;)

Comment: @Marc can you please provide a link to `mysql_numrows` in the php docs?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can add @:

```
if (!@mysql_result($result3,0)) {
    $location = "Not found";
} else $location = mysql_result($result3,0,0);
```

Second, you can check `mysql_num_rows(result3)` before `mysql_result` call.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - Yes. But coder should know all features of the language he is coding on. I think that the second variant is preferable too.

Comment: Please do not recommend the operator `@`.  It instantly gives code a bad smell.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into how to set your error and warning levels in php ini - usually you want a s little output on prod as possible.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

However, here, the code that would generate that error is:

```
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
```

That is the line you should be writing your if or "or die" statements around:

```
$result3 = mysql_query($query3)or die($location = "not found");
```

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns FALSE when the query fails, not when it returns zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using OOP; using a database class to handle interaction with your DB.

But, basically you want to check if there are any rows, before trying to bring back the results.

Try checking with "mysql_num_rows" in your "if" statement:

```
if (!mysql_num_rows($result3)) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Mysql_query returns false if nothing is found so a simple :

```
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);

if (mysql_affected_rows($result3) == 0) {
    $location = "Not found";
} else  $location = mysql_result($result3,0,0);
```

Should do it.

Comment: In this situation, `mysql_query()` should return FALSE when MySQL server crashes, the connection drops or similar cases. A query that returns no rows is not an error.

Comment: The error the OP reported is caused by the mysql_result command because the mysql_query above returned no result. My answer deals with the cause not with the symptom.

Comment: Méa culpa, I did not understand your comment. mysql_query returns false only if the sql statement caused an error. Not if the row count is 0. I'm correcting my answer based on that.

Comment: From the php docs: "_Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier._"